# JQuery Serialize Form - Kendo UI Duplicating Inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization, kendo-ui

I'm working on posting a form and noticed that Kendo UI screws with the form fields when serialized and creates a duplicate field in the serialized object.  I want to know if anyone has come across this before and if there's a solution.

So let's say I want to do a JQuery AJAX post of a form.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/MyController",
    data: formData
});
```

I can have a simple form like this.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
</form>
```

If I want to serialize my form data (used in the formData variable), I would do this.

```
var formData = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
```

The output in the console would look like this.

```
[Object { name="firstName",  value="John"}]
```

Now the problem.
If I'm using Kendo UI and I'm making a dropdown or combobox out of that input and I try to serialize the form, another input (the one with the underscore) is recognized.

```
[Object { name="firstName_input",  value="John"}, Object { name="firstName",  value="John"}]
```

If you're not familiar, Kendo UI uses a simple input to create comboboxes or dropdowns with remote calls to an api for data.  Here's how the combobox is created.

```
var firstNameComboBox= $('#firstName').kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "Select a Name",
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "ID",
    change: myChangeFunction,      //On change event
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/api/MyController/MyAction",
                data: { }
            },
        }
    }
}).data("kendoComboBox");
```

Comment: Can you add the html of the input, after the kendo comboBox is created?

Comment: Well Kendo creates the combobox out of the input.  It has to be there first.  It needs something to target.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but use F12 and inspect the html. Kendo maybe doing something your are not aware of

Comment: Yeah it looks like Kendo is creating that second input as "firstName_input" for the combobox, then it sets the display to none for the original.
So I guess the serialization is doing what it's supposed to do, picking up all of the form elements, but I would hope Kendo would have a way to allow serializing a form that uses it's elements.

Comment: You are posting to a API controller right? So the firstName_input would just get ignored since it's not a property on the object your posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Telerik/Kendo UI team

The described behavior is expected. Basically, the ComboBox renders a second input element that holds the selected text. The widget adds a *name* attribute to that input element using the following *"{name}_input"* format. As you probably know when an input element has a *name* attribute, it becomes [successful](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) and the form will post it.

This is done in favor to server platforms that returns the same posted page when there are errors. This helps the server developers to get that value and returns it as a ComboBox [text](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-text) configuration option.

I do not believe this would be a problem to the developer that consumes the posted value, as it should match the POST payload with the model fields/names.